# rspec + capybara rails 4 - rake integration testing fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, capybara

I'm trying to test devise sign in, sign out and all the other scenarios, however I cannot get a single scenario to past, lets take login failure

in my feature I have

```
scenario 'user cannot sign in if not registered' do
   login_as('user2@example.com', 'meow')
   visit overviews_path
   save_and_open_page
    expect(page).to have_content I18n.t 'devise.failure.not_found_in_database', authentication_keys: 'email'
end
```

I also have the sign_in helper setup as;

```
 def sign_in(email, password)
  user.confirm!
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in 'Email', with: email
  fill_in 'password', with: password
  click_button 'Log in'
end
```

however this create an error;

```
expected to find text "Invalid email or password." in "TypeError at /overviews ======================= > no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer spec/features/users/sign_in_spec.rb, line 14
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You named your helper method `sign_in` but you're calling `login_as` in your scenario. You should use one approach or the other, not both.

UPDATE: OK, rechecked the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara), and you should either use your own helper so that you're emulating an actual user signing in, or the `login_as` provided by Warden, in which case make sure you're included this in your tests / rspec setup:

```
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!
```

On a side note, you should confirm your user in your factory/fixture, not in your helper method (where it's probably not defined).

Comment: Thanks for that, I ended up removing the additional helper and moved back to the warden login_as, i have ensured that I included the warden Test::Helpers however I now get a different issue

    Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content I18n.t     'devise.failure.not_found_in_database', authentication_keys: 'email'
       expected to find text "Invalid email or password." in "TypeError at /overviews ======================= > no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: What's your overviews controller like? What line is the 'implicit conversion of symbol into integer' triggered from? That's a different issue than the login stuff.